# Android custom sorting using comparable

Tags: java, android, comparable

I have a little problem with this snippet of code:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(EventResponse o) {
    int compare1 = startTime.compareTo(o.startTime);
    if (compare1 == 0 && o.myProviderId != null && o.providerId != null) {
        return o.providerId.compareTo(o.myProviderId) != 0 ? -1 : 0;
    } else {
        return compare1;
    }
}
```

I have EventResponse class which i have created that implements Comparable interface, o.myProviderId is ID of currently signed in user (into application) and o.providerId is ID of user that is assigned to particular object (EventResponse).
What I need to achieve is if there are two objects with the same startTime to show objects assigned to me first and then objects assigned to some other provider/s.

This code snippet should (and I think it did in the past) do the trick but I get error message stating: "Comparison method violates its general contract".

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The violation of the contract often means that the comparator is not providing the correct or consistent value when comparing objects.

For example :

```
if (compare1 == 0 && o.myProviderId != null && o.providerId != null) {
    return o.providerId.compareTo(o.myProviderId) != 0 ? -1 : 0;
}
```

So, what happens when `o.providerId.compareTo(o.myProviderId)` gives you `1` or `-1`. In both scenario you are going to return `-1` isn't it ?

Instead, why not simply return what gets return from `compareTo` ?

```
if (compare1 == 0 && o.myProviderId != null && o.providerId != null) {
    return o.providerId.compareTo(o.myProviderId);
}
```

Comment: Behaviour you have described is actually what I need. I need objects that have `o.providerId == o.myProviderId ` shown first and all other objects after them. So I need to return -1 in that case.

Comment: Both propertyes are of type UUID

Comment: @TipsyFingers You can't do what you want.. there are some rules

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve described behaviour?

Comment: @TipsyFingers I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.. logically, whatever you are trying is incorrect. Just imagine, you are saying if `1>2` and `2>1` then `return greater`; how is it possible ?